# Repeater, DataGrid or other options

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, repeater

I need a control that will load 500-1000 rows at once, no paging, lightweight,   sortable, color code each row based on "status" and is able to repeat header every Nth rows.

I was think of using a repeater and was wondering if this control would support all options.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on on the data.  Do you want a grid like layout or do you want a template to lay it out.  But either or will work.  [Here is a link for sorting in a repeater](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/sorting-data-in-a-datalist-or-repeater-control-vb)

Comment: I want a grid like layout but the lightweight of the repeater. I think I've found some examples of repeating the header every Nth rows but i'm not sure if it will mess up sorting if it's added. What about freezing header in a repeater, is that possible?

Comment: If you want some functionality like that couldn't you just create your own "header"?

Answer (score 0):

A `Repeater` doesn't support sorting on its own, but you can add sorting to the control by sorting the original object that you bind the data to. If you store this object in the `Session`, then your users can sort several times without waiting for new results from the database (for instance).

As far as repeating the header every N rows, I don't think there's a way to do that. There are plenty of other options for copying the header (using jQuery or JavaScript, for instance), but that's smelly if you ask me. You'd probably be better off using some CSS or JavaScript to float the header row (once the user scrolls past the header) and keeping it at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GridView.  Here's a little demo with row statuses, header repetition, and sorting.

e.g.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="GridViewDemo.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>
    <style>
        tr.Good { background-color: green; }
        tr.Bad { background-color: red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView id="GV" runat="server"
            OnRowDataBound="GV_RowDataBound"        
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AllowSorting="true"
            OnSorting="GV_Sort"
        >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id"            SortExpression="Id"/>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name"/>
            </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridViewDemo
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GV.DataSource = GetDataSource();
            GV.DataBind();
        }

    protected void GV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
        {
            SetCssClass(e.Row);

            if (e.Row.RowIndex % 10 == 0)
            {
                AddHeader (e);            
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetCssClass(GridViewRow row)
    {
        row.CssClass += ((Entity)row.DataItem).Status;
    }

    private void AddHeader (GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Id" }); 
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Name" }); 
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table);
              tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + 1, row);
    }

    protected void GV_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Entity> sortedList = GetDataSource();
        if (e.SortExpression == "Id")
        {
            if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                sortedList.Sort((x, y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id));
            else
                sortedList.Sort((x, y) => y.Id.CompareTo(x.Id));
        }
        else if (e.SortExpression == "Name")
        {
            if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                sortedList.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
            else
                sortedList.Sort((x, y) => y.Name.CompareTo(x.Name));
        }

        GV.DataSource = sortedList;
        GV.DataBind();
    }

    protected List<Entity> GetDataSource ()
    {
        List<Entity> result = new List<Entity>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            result.Add(new Entity() { Id=i, Name="foo" });
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Entity.cs

```
using System;

namespace GridViewDemo
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status 
        { 
            get
            {
                if (Id % 42 == 0) { return "Good"; };
                if (Id % 111 == 0) { return "Bad"; };
                return "Normal";    
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

(a few little bugs but you get the idea...)